If the sides AB,BC,CD,DA of a quadrilateral are in the descending order of magnitude, show that angles CDA> angle CBA
I got this question in the book "Challenge and Thrill of Pre-College Mathematics"
What i have tried: i know that using the angle-side realtion property i have,
In $\Delta ACD:CD>DA \implies \angle CAD > \angle ACD$
In $\Delta ABC: AB>BC \implies \angle BCA.\angle BAC$ also that the sum of the quadrilateral will be equal to $360$ degrees. but i can't find a relation between $\angle ADC$ and $\angle ABC$ as the two triangles have common base but unequal sides.

Unsure, but I merely suspect that the law of cosines works here, constructing the auxiliary line segment $~\overline{AC}.$  Notice that the $~\cos(\theta)~$ is a strictly decreasing function for $~0^\circ < \theta < 180^\circ.$

The claim is not true.
For the numerical example, take $AB = 10, BC = 9, CA = 8, CD = 8.5, DA = 0.6$.
Note that the triangle inequality is satisfied for $ABC$ and $CDA$, so this is a valid construction.
Then we can calculate that $\cos \angle ABC = 0.65, \cos \angle CDA = 0.844$.
Because we are dividing by $DA$ which is very small, hence $\cos \angle CDA$ becomes very large.
For a picture to determine the locus of $D$ could be for a counterexample:

Start with any triangle $ABC$, draw the circumcircle (in red).
Draw the perpendicular bisector of $AC$.

The condition that $AB > BC$ means that $B$ is on the side of $C$.
The condition that $CD > DA$ means that $D$ is on the side of $A$.


Reflect point $D$ across $AC$ to $D'$, so $B, D'$ are on the same side of $AC$.

Notice that $\angle CDA = \angle CD'A$.
The goal of $ \angle ABC < \angle CDA = \angle CD'A$ means that $D'$ is not contained in the circle $ABC$.


Draw the circle center $C$ with radius $BC$ (in blue) .

The condition that $BC > CD$ means that $D, D'$ is contained in this circle.


Now, clearly here are points that are 1/ in the blue circle, 2/ not in the red circle, 3/ On the same side of $AC$ as $B$, 4/ On the same side of the perpendicular bisector as $A$.

Take any such point to be $D'$. Then, the reflection to $D$ provides a counter example.
Note that we likewise have $AD$ being very small in comparison to the other values.





